# How to use Powershell send email

Tags: json, powershell, function

I am trying to add a in-line code and not a function to send an email to the below code, also would like to use the $json in the summary and the body like below, but I ran into an error where the **summary cannot be null** (Just trying to use the same summary in JSON)

```
$VIPResults = Get-NSVIPAlertingStatus

if ($null -ne $VIPResults)
{
    foreach ($R in ($VIPResults | Where-Object Status -notmatch "Up|Out Of Service"))
    {
        if ($R.status -eq "Down")
        {
            $Stauts = $R.Status
            $Severity = "5"
        }
        Elseif ($R.status -eq "Resolved")
        {   
            $Stauts = $R.Status
            $Severity = "0"
        }

        Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date): Send Alert: Netscaler $($R.name) on $($R.netscalername) is $($R.Status)" -Verbose
        $JSON = @"
        {
            "summary": "Netscaler $($R.name) on $($R.netscalername) is $($R.Status)",
            "node": "$($R.netscalername)",
            "team": "",
            "severity": $Severity,
            "sop_link": "",
            "category": "Netscaler component $($R.name)",
            "integration": "" 
        }
"@
        
        Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date):se" -Verbose
        $Json
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http:\\test.com -Method Post -Body \$Json -ContentType application/json -Verbose
    }
}
```

I tried to add this below the invoke webrequest line, is that correct to place the $mailsplat line here

```
  Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date):se" -Verbose
    $Json
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http:\\test.com -Method Post -Body \$Json -ContentType application/json -Verbose

  $MailSplat = @{
        To         = "test@.com"
        From       = "no-reply@.com"
        Subject    = $JSON.Summary
        Body       = $JSON
        SmtpServer = "hub.test.com"
        BodyAsHtml = $true
    }

    Send-MailMessage @MailSplat
}}
```

Comment: Please post the _exact error message_, in full. FWIW `-Body \$Json` looks very wrong, should probably be `-Body $Json`

Comment: that was a typo, Parameter 'summary' cannot be null or empty

Comment: Is that an error you get from `Get-NSVIPAlertingStatus` or `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: on send-mailmessage, basically, I tried something like this, not sure if I am placing the $mailsplat at the correct place and $json.summary are the 2 points that I need

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. [Update your existing post instead](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76668283/edit)

Comment: Ahh, I see now. `$JSON` contains a string, strings have to `Summary` property. Perhaps you meant to do `Subject = ($JSON |ConvertFrom-Json).Summary`?

Comment: ah ok, that works, and the body = ($JSON |ConvertFrom-Json)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the `$JSON` variable contains a *string*, so `$JSON.Summary` will evaluate to `$null` because strings don't have a `Summary` property.

Use `ConvertFrom-Json` to convert the json to an object you can interact with:

```
$payloadObject = $JSON |ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now you can interact with the `Summary` property, as well as converting the object properties to an HTML list for the email body!

```
  $MailSplat = @{
        To         = "test@.com"
        From       = "no-reply@.com"
        Subject    = $payloadData.Summary
        Body       = $payloadData |ConvertTo-Html -As List
        SmtpServer = "hub.test.com"
        BodyAsHtml = $true
    }

    Send-MailMessage @MailSplat
```